# Does the value of $i$ affect the determinant of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant, matrix-equations

Let $B = \left(\begin {array}{ccc|c} a & b & c. & d
\\ 0 & e & f & g\\
0 & 0 & h & i  \end{array}\right)$ \ be a $\text{REF}$ that belongs to a non-homogenous linear system.

$(1)$ If $ i \ne 0 $, then, $ \det(B) = \begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\ 0 & e & f \\ 0 & 0 & h     \end{vmatrix}$ $\ne 0$.

**$\quad \quad$ False. We have that $\det(B) = aeh $, so $i$ does not affect the value of the determinant. Even if $ i \ne 0,$ $ \det(B) \ne 0 $ when $ a,e,h \ne 0 $**

$(2)$ If the $3^{\text{rd}}$ column is a pivot, then the system has a unique solution.

**$\quad \quad$ False. Let $ c,d \ne 0$, and $a,b,e,f,g,h,i = 0.$ The system has infinitely many solutions.**

I am not sure if my reasons are correct for $(1),$ does $i$ indicate any property of the matrix, which would change the determinant?

Comment: $i$ does not affect the determinant. The only case where I think $i$ affects the determinant is if it is given that the linear system represented by $B$ is consistent.

Comment: @player3236 Thanks. But, whether or not the system is consistent, depends on the values of abcdefghi right? Then, the statement is still false? would my reason be valid?

Comment: Ah I see your point. Yes your reasoning is okay.